# /run_script_view gives "RpcException: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" on ghostnet

Tags: smart-contracts, rpc

So I am trying to run a view operation with a post method on ghostnet:
https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_script_view/

with this data:
{“contract”:“KT1Ce3eh8BNXk4KVfjWy6VXoLk2Sd2GPQKzK”,“view”:“view_inventory_of”,“input”:“{\u0022string\u0022:\u0022tz1Sdn7L63NaB3v5N5YUVR8Mt7BVn7z2iM2B\u0022}“,”chain_id”:“NetXnHfVqm9iesp”,“unparsing_mode”:“Readable”}

but my response is:

RpcException: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

“input” in this case is {“string”:“tz1Sdn7L63NaB3v5N5YUVR8Mt7BVn7z2iM2B”}

And the view im running is “view_inventory_of” on

https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1Ce3eh8BNXk4KVfjWy6VXoLk2Sd2GPQKzK/views

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was merged 4 months ago and was not included in jakarta protocol.

You can inspect its availability by querying the following endpoint:

`https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz/describe/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_script_view`

It is available in [kathmandu testnet](https://rpc.kathmandunet.teztnets.xyz/describe/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_script_view).

Taquito, currently uses the `run_code` entrypoint to simulate the view call.

Comment: why is ghostnet on jakarta protocol and not on the latest?

Comment: It is a long-running test network that aims to run the same protocol as mainnet, and will only upgrade to the new protocol `kathmandu` once the proposal reaches the "adoption" phase.

Answer (score 1):

Teztnets Octez version is 13.0 (https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz/version)
Octez v13.0 doesn't have such endpoint ([OpenAPI](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/jakarta-openapi.json))
To `run_script_view` you need Octez v14.0 and later ([OpenAPI](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/kathmandu-openapi.json#/default/post_helpers_scripts_run_script_view))